# Where does copper form?

Tags: electrochemistry

[image]
 I thought zn and cu both lose 2e- to pt but someone is telling me it's wrong]

Comment: If both Zn and Cu were to lose electrons, what would receive these electrons?

Comment: the cu2+ from cuso4?

Comment: Which one? We have two separate compartments with CuSO4.

Comment: the cuso4 for both platinum?wouldnt pt a and pt b both receiving2e- since cu and zn are oxidized when connected with pt?

Comment: You might want to check again the oxidation state of Pt, and whether it can be reduced.

Comment: @donnny consider also respecting electrostatic neutrality. Separating of few coulombs would create very mighty force.

Comment: Zn doesn't lose electrons to Pt: it rarely participates in cell reactions (it's called inert electrode!)

Comment: Unless Pt is just passing them to $\ce{Cu2+}$